Persistent Knocking Sound from New Bradford White Water Heater – Even When Water Isn’t Being Heated
I have a Bradford White water heater (model RG250T6N-394) installed about 1 year and 8 months ago to replace my 17-year-old State Industries unit, which worked flawlessly but was replaced due to age.
Since installation, the new Bradford White unit has developed a persistent knocking or clicking noise, and I’m concerned it may be related to the gas pilot or something similar failing to start. It’s hard to tell—I’m not an expert. What’s odd is that the noise occurs even when the water isn’t being heated. I’ve contacted Bradford White technical support, and they insist that it is normal. However, when I asked for documentation to confirm this, they stopped responding.
Additional Information

The unit produces hot water as expected, but the noise persists.
The water heater is located in the utility room in the basement. It’s
in pristine condition, and no one has bumped into or tampered with
it.
The noise started recently, after the unit had been running quietly
for over a year.

My Questions

Has anyone experienced a similar knocking sound with their Bradford White water heater?
Could this noise indicate a gas pilot issue or something more serious?
Is this really a “normal” noise for this model, or should I push for a warranty inspection?
Should I be concerned, given that the noise happens even when the heater isn’t actively running?

Service calls in my area (Seattle) can be costly, so I’d appreciate any advice or insights before proceeding. Thanks!

Since we cannot hear the knock or click, you'll have to describe it more. Does it sound like it's from the bottom or the top of the heater? Turn your head so your ears are vertical when listening for it. "Knock" means to me a dull thud, like someone knocking on a door. "Click" means to me the sharp snick or tick like when a thermostat switches on or off. Which does it sound like to you? Or something else? If a dull thud, is there a metallic ring to it, like metal being knocked, or just a dull thud, like wood being knocked?

https://1drv.ms/u/s!AgqLsOua0ad1v7g7y3ambHw1CAmEKg
Definitely coming from the bottom of the water heater. I recorded the sound…

The posted noise is very quiet. It sounds like the low dull popping noise a gas burner makes when the gas flow is very low, just enough to barely keep up enough concentration to burn. This heater has a pilot light. Since the noise happens even when the heater is not heating, I'd suspect the pilot light. See if the pilot flame is popping on and off.
